# What should our domain name be?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name ******************************webapps.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

It's all in the title.

Please suggest only available domain names (Check first) and **one suggestion per answer** so we can easily see what's preferred.

> When considering domain names, keep
>   these basic guidelines in mind:
>
> ```
> * The domain name should be available.
> * Prefer dot-com names over other top-level domains.
> * Prefer non-hyphenated names.
> ```
>
> Source: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/

Comment: Is the use of available country codes for domain hacks allowed? e.g. interface.to or user.io or use.it (ok, probably not use.it, but you get the idea).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain

Comment: "Prefer dot-com names over other top-level domains".

Comment: @whybird haha, use.it would be sweet.

Comment: "__Prefer__ dot-com names over other top-level domains"

Comment: No direct suggestion, but maybe we can take it a bit broader then just "UI". Related themes that come to mind are interaction design and usability.

Comment: I'd really like to see some design suggestions accompanying these names. I feel like a few of them don't really inspire me when I try to think of a site design and logo, whereas others do. There's a separate question here on meta for posting designs and logo ideas. It'd be nice to see some suggestions there!

Answer (score 10):

Tough question. From the few urls I've tried expertui.com is the only one available. So..

**ExpertUI.com**

Available

Comment: +1 for the clearest on-topic suggestion.

Comment: Love this domain

Comment: +1 really like this one. It says everything this site is supposed to be.

Comment: I think this could be too easily mistaken for a site about UI code. We seem to have that problem already with ui.stackexhange.com. The domain should somehow imply that the site's about design rather than implementation.

Comment: I don't like this, it reminds me of ExpertExchange

Answer (score 10):

[image: happy user]

**[happyuser.com](http://happyuser.com)**

Inspired by [Kathy Sierra's Happy User Peak](http://headrush.typepad.com/photos/uncategorized/2007/04/06/featuritis.jpg) and parallelling superuser.com

The domain is [taken, but parked](http://whois.domaintools.com/happyuser.com).

Edit: Here's a question where I've posted [an example of what happyuser.com could look like](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like/92#92)!

Comment: +1 Kinda like this one.

Comment: ProzacUser.com is available

Comment: What is this.. I don't even...

Comment: +1 for being memorable, even though ExpertUI is more on-topic.

Comment: Ughh... please don't give domain squatters money (and this one is owned by domain squatters).

Answer (score 6):

**LeastSurprise.com**

available

edit: I picked this because the principle of least surprise/astonishment applies to interfaces, and makes it look less like a design enthusiast site, and more like a UI/UX experts' site.

Comment: Sounds cool. Not directly related to UI, but when you think about it.. Seems good to me.

Comment: @Jouke I think it's related, it's just also related to several other fields. May be too broad but it's all I've come up with so far

Comment: @Carson That's what makes it fun I suppose..

Comment: Ironically, the name makes you think. I don't think that's a good thing.

Comment: It's totally a good thing that it makes you think -- for example, if someone hears about it at a conference, they'll be more likely to remember it when they get home. I like this better than my suggestion (TabOverflow).

Comment: There's a difference, though, between memorable and "makes you think". IMO, something like ExpertUI.com is memorable and it's more obvious at a glance what the site is about. More people will be familiar with the term "UI" than with the principle of least astonishment. The domain name is part of the user interface. For this site, above all the other StackExchange sites, it's important that the user doesn't have to think in regards to the UI.

Comment: I too don't like this one at all. Sorry folks! However, it seems to be the most popular.

Comment: Agree with @Robert. It's a good thing that the name makes you think. It's an insider's term, an identifying mark that says to experts, *we're part of your tribe*. Remember, "the experts will attract the enthusiasts…"

Comment: -1 Don't Make Me Think.

Comment: Here's a concept for the logo. http://i.imgur.com/KtdHO.png

Comment: Wow, I didn't think my silly domain name would gain all this attention and controversy :D -- To clarify, I did pick the name to be a little non-obvious, an "insider's term", to signal that the site is primarily for people who understand what it means. Look at stackoverflow; when I talk about that site I get blank stares all around: "what does that even mean?"

Comment: Title says nothing about interfaces or even technology really.

Comment: It's a principle related to interfaces, and interfaces aren't necessarily related to technology either

Answer (score 5):

**TabOverflow.com**

Available

Answer (score 4):

**InterfaceAddict.com**

Available.

There are only two industries that call their clients 'users' ...

Comment: "There are only two industries that call their clients 'users' ..." - lol awesome

Answer (score 2):

UserFocus.com appears to be parked and unused.

Answer (score 1):

**UIAddict.com**

it has to be an addiction

Answer (score 1):

uxexchange.com

(This site should be merged with that one.)

Answer (score 0):

**UIMaster.com**

UIMasters was taken, but this sort of resembles superuser.com so I guess it's all right.

Answer (score 0):

**uioverflow.com**

Available

Comment: if you guys don't grab this one up I might...

Answer (score 0):

**Refitts.com**

as in Re:Fitts law.

Available, but you would also want refits.com. That is parked and marked as perhaps for sale.

(p.s. I would not even vote this up myself, but I think it is worth putting things out there as food for thought for others)

Comment: Wow, I'd always thought it was spelled "Fitz" ;-P. Too hard to spell, IMO.

Comment: Actually, it's [Fitts's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts's_law) :-)

Comment: -1 never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

#### justui.com

```
pronounce - Just UI
```

> - available(parked)
> - simple
> - easy to remember

Comment: Our slogan could be "Just UI it!" ;P

Comment: I prefer ExpertUI since Expert is more descriptive than the "Just" filler word.

Answer (score 0):

interfaceanswers.com

is available

Answer (score -1):

**InterfaceArchitecture.com**

*Not* availabe, but there is nothing there. It is owned by a Canadian company.

```
  Interface Architecture Inc
  #230 - 11590 Cambie Rd
  Richmond, BC V6X3Z5
  CA
```

email is admin@ the domain in question.

All the other .org etc. variants are available.

Comment: I live near richmond, want me to drive over there and rough him up a bit? :)

Answer (score -1):

## AngryFruitSalad.com

Parked, might be buyable.

> angry fruit salad: n.
>
> A bad visual-interface design that uses too many colors. (This term derives, of course, from the bizarre day-glo colors found in canned fruit salad.) Too often one sees similar effects from interface designers using color window systems such as X; there is a tendency to create displays that are flashy and attention-getting but uncomfortable for long-term use.
>
> [source](http://catb.org/jargon/html/A/angry-fruit-salad.html)

Comment: -1 too obscure. Angry, overweight stay-at-home moms will be asking for fruit salad recipes.

Answer (score -2):

userinterface.org ? (so obvious)

Taken.

Comment: .com must be taken then.

Comment: According to the check I just did, .org and .net are actually taken too :(

Answer (score -2):

**FittsLaw.org**

.com is taken, but .org. .net, .biz, .info and .co are available.

Answer (score -2):

**Outerface.org**

.com is taken, all other common variants available.

Answer (score -2):

**FaceInter.com**

Available

Answer (score -2):

**interfaceoverflow.com**

Available

Answer (score -2):

**LeastAstonishment.com**

available

alternative to [LeastSurprise.com](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-name-be/44#44), since "least surprise" is harder to say. This one is a bit more to type though.

Comment: -1 I don't want to type a long word like Astonishment unless I absolutely have to.

Answer (score -2):

user-interface.com

It's a premium domain name, but it's available.

Comment: don't like the hyphen.

Answer (score -3):

**UIParadigms.com**

Available

Answer (score -3):

**UIXchange.com**

Available.

Comment: Good, but easily confused with "uiExchange", which is taken (parked)

Comment: Good point @Robert.

Answer (score -5):

**InterUserFace.com**

Available

Comment: Too confusing.. i'd always get it wrong.