# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion

Please post any ideas you have for what the site design and logo should be.

Jin (the SE designer) recently said on the [web apps meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/design-ideas-for-web-applications-site) that he prefers greyscale images, but feel free to post designs in colour.

Comment: Shouldn't we decide on a name first? I imagine the name would impact the logo and site design to some extent.

Comment: @Rahul - they could go hand in hand, but equally someone could come up with a good colour scheme/design that could accommodate almost any logo. Anyway the question is here ready to accept answers.

Comment: Can't wait to see what all you designers come up with!

Comment: So, anyone got anything else? My answer is lonely down there.

Comment: Related: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/improved-ux-logo

Answer (score 3):

Okay, let's get the ball rolling then!

Here's an idea of what [my proposed happyuser.com](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-name-be/70#70) could look like:

[image]

You can see what it looks like in the browser here: http://happyuser.quplo.com/

This is actually sort of fun since I was always dissatisfied with StackOverflow's initial design (subsequent sites have become much better) and always wanted to have a crack at rebalancing certain elements. If we're to be a site about user interfaces, I think it would be appropriate to iterate on the StackExchange UI as much as we can. As such my first attempt (~15 mins spent) focuses on improving legibility of the questions while reducing the visual weight of most other elements. I've always found many StackExchange pages to be too busy.

This is just the homepage as I haven't done anything else yet. Should be fun to try the question display page too!

Comment: I don't like the beta style highlight on questions (you know, where it says '8 answers'). Otherwise really cool. I like the superuser logo twist.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I didn't hide that one yet. :)

Comment: Updated it a bit.

Comment: Nice design, but we can't use a CSS3 design, at least not until IE9 comes out.

Comment: Of course we can, ever heard of progressive enhancement? All functionality on that page will work in all browsers. I just added -webkit-transitions for snazzy crossfading links in webkit :)

Comment: @sruly is that a joke?

Comment: @Rahul: `@-webkit-keyframes rot { 0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } } body { -webkit-animation: rot 2s linear; }`