# What is our community about in one brief sentence?

Tags: discussion

In response to [Robert's blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), let's step away from the [domain name discussion](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-domain-name-be) for a second and consider our elevator pitch:

**What is StackExchange UI about, in one sentence?**

This is a different question than [the one answered in the faq](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq), which mostly talks about who it is *for*.